Active Camera do not update 3D view camera view
Having a very weird issue with Blender 4.0 and no matter what I Bing or Google, I do not see a solution posted anywhere about it. And have browse all over this site and cannot find a solution to my issue. With that said, here it is the issue.
Here is a copy of blend file with only a cube of course.
Normal Camera Behaviour: On Blender 3D view, when you press Numpad 0 toggles the camera view, then if you navigate into Properties > Scene > Camera and select a camera, the camera view changes to that selected camera. Correct?
The Issue: Not now. The issue I'm having, and I cannot say how to replicate it because I do not have a clue how it happened, what combination of keys I might have clicked or what else done caused it. So now, when I change camera on the Scene Tab, the camera view in the 3D view do not change to the selected camera. Stays with the camera that was active initially when Numpad 0 was pressed.

Of course, when something like this happens, the first thing I do is to check if Local Camera property has been activated and have an object or a camera selected hitting Ctrl+0 by accident, but it is not the case.

I also tried to select the camera by making it active in the Collection Tree Properties with the same luck. This would be same action as selecting an object/camera and set it as an Active Camera View. But it does not change the 3D view camera.

Granted, when I do the changes, the camera selected is the camera used for rendering. That's not the issue here. The issue is in the 3D view, when I switch cameras, I want the camera activated with Numpad 0 to change to the camera selected on the Scene > Camera tab, which I use often to make sure changes that I made to the objects do not conflict with camera position and angle. With this issue, every time I change a camera in the properties, to see it active in the 3D View viewport, I need to toggle Numpad 0 each time.

This consumes a lot of time, especially when I have to work with 250 scenes in a very limited time.
I am pretty certain that a combination of keys I pressed might have caused the issue, but I can't find anywhere, not even in the Blender manual online, of a process that I can use to reset this to its default behavior.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to do so.

Hm, that's strange. I would have suspected the Local Camera is enabled since some users do not know about this feature. Could you upload your file to https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question? I guess the model is not the necessary (because I do not think it causes this), just the scene with its settings, the cameras and probably a default cube to look at should do...

It is very likely because you are in the isolation mode (/ on numpad).
This happened to me, and the 3D Viewport update camera view between cameras in one click again after i quit isolation mode. This happens in 4.2 and I don't know if other versions suffer from this issue.

That was it, just that simple. The slash on the numpad was the trick.
